# HTTPS Redirect from non secure server gives Error Message in Browser

Tags: email, ssl, redirect, https, dns

Decided to move from a shared hosting platform to an AWS based Hosting Environment (Acquia Cloud specifically). This environment doesn't offer e-mail services so the client kept the shared hosting to continue using that for email (they didn't want to spend the extra $2400 per year for G Suite Email Hosting).

In order to achieve this, we worked with the new host to use the shared site as a pass through so that the emails still go there, and the web traffic goes to the new server.

The nameservers go to the shared host. We have a DNS Cname www.example.com pointed to the new AWS server and the A record pointed at the shared host. It was the only way to keep the email still running. When we pointed the A record, that's when email went down. This was the suggestion from the hosting company.

So now if they go to http://example.com, https://www.example.com, http://www.example.com and www.example.com it all works fine, no problem. However if they go to https://example.com they get this issue right here:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4urX.png): [image: Your Connection is Not Private]
When we moved to the new host, the SSL certificate went with it. This causes some Search Engine Issues. I have an .htaccess redirect set up, but it still gives that error.

This is what myself and both hosting companies could best come up with, and it's not a great solution.

Is there a solution other than:

- Carrying an SSL Certificate for both accounts
- Moving email to a 3rd party provider like gmail

If there isn't we are going to go with one of these options, but I figured I'd ask first.

Comment: Seems like you have two separate issues here. Mail should be fixed by setting correct MX records (ask shared hosting company for that info).

Comment: have you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The only issue here is your certificate does not have example.com in your certificate SAN (Subject Alternative Name). By default, you should get this in your SAN but few CA don't provide it under SAN unless and until you tell them. Kindly find the image for your reference. If you have windows OS just save your certificate file in **.crt** or **.cer** format to view the SAN. 
[image]

Else you can use below command if you Linux OS and the certificate is installed on the server

```
 openssl s_client -connect website.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep DNS
```

It will list the SAN